# Gutenberg; Rich Text/HTML for Metadata Textarea Control in Back End

Tags: tinymce, block-editor, html-editor

I've properly registered a Gutenberg block that consists of a textarea control to store metadata for a post. In the old days, I simply rendered a `wp_editor` on the `edit-form-advanced` hook which had full TinyMCE editing capability and stored the textarea html on the `transition_post_status` hook.

Inside the Gutenberg environment, using the TextareaControl component, how do I bring full editing capability into the textarea control? My basic setup only shows plain text to input into the control. I guess I could hand code the html but it seems like I should be able to used the editing toolbar to achieve this.

I should add that I'm looking for full TinyMCE editing including ordered/unordered lists. The pre-formatted Toolbar isn't featured enough.

---

Edit:
Here is the js I used to render the Gutenberg block. Pretty basic.

```
( function( wp ) {
    var el = wp.element.createElement;
    var registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType;
    var TextareaControl = wp.components.TextareaControl;
    var RichText = wp.editor.RichText;
    var AlignmentToolbar = wp.editor.AlignmentToolbar;

    registerBlockType( 'my-gutenberg/my-block', {
        title: 'The title',
        icon: 'email-alt',
        category: 'common',
        keywords: ['email'],

        attributes: {
            blockValue: {
                type: 'string',
                source: 'meta',
                meta: 'the_meta'
            }
        },

        edit: function( props ) {
            var className = props.className;
            var setAttributes = props.setAttributes;

            function updateBlockValue( blockValue ) {
                setAttributes({ blockValue });
            }

            return el(
                'div',
                { className: className },
                el( TextareaControl, {
                    label: 'The label',
                    value: props.attributes.blockValue,
                    onChange: updateBlockValue
                } )
            );
        },

        // No information saved to the block
        // Data is saved to post meta via attributes
        save: function() {
            return null;
        }
    } );

} )( window.wp );
```

Comment: You may be looking for the RichText component. If you'll post your code you'll have a better chance of someone recognizing what's wrong and how to fix it. :)

Comment: @WebElaine added the js as you suggested.

Comment: @WebElaine I need more than just RichText. I need some basic HTML editing capability including unordered lists.

Comment: That's a bit counter to how the Block Editor imagines things - each separate component is typically its own block. If you have a set/templated structure, you can add multiple types of inputs - i.e. say each block has a heading, a list, and an image - you just use multiple components and they all become part of the one block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy way to achieve what you wanted:

From the `edit` callback, return a `class` which extends the [`ClassicEdit` component](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/classic/edit.js) used with the Classic editor block. And in your block's `attributes`, make sure `content` is set (in the question, it's `blockValue`). Tried and tested working properly:

```js
var el = wp.element.createElement;
var ClassicEdit; // An instance of the private ClassicEdit class.

wp.blocks.registerBlockType( 'my-gutenberg/my-block', {
    attributes: {
        content: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'meta',
            meta: 'the_meta'
        }
    },
    edit: function( props ) {
        if ( ! ClassicEdit ) {
            var block = wp.blocks.getBlockType( 'core/freeform' );
            ClassicEdit = ( class extends block.edit {
                componentDidMount() {
                    // Call the parent method to setup TinyMCE, etc.
                    block.edit.prototype.componentDidMount.call( this );

                    // Change the toolbar's title - to your block's.
                    jQuery( '#toolbar-' + this.props.clientId )
                        .attr( 'data-placeholder', 'My Title' );
                }
            } );
        }
        return el( ClassicEdit, props );
    },
    save: function( props ) {
    },
    ...
} );
```

But you'd want to [copy these CSS](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/5ally/b95cb3e2722977654839f815637ea03a/raw/7e97fe35f02034bfb6bb640f4cf0c54fe23ad189/my-block.css) and make sure to replace the `my-guternberg/my-block` with the proper block name.

For advanced coding, you could copy [the component file](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/classic/edit.js), edit it anyway you like, and use it with your block's `edit` option — `edit: MyClassicEdit`.

And [here's the code](https://gist.github.com/5ally/b95cb3e2722977654839f815637ea03a) I used for testing.

### Preview

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the hard work you put in on this. Very kind of you. Couple of questions. 1. I thought the ClassicEditor is destined for the bit bucket by the WordPress team. 2. Not sure I understand how the block content is directed to the meta table.

Comment: 1) Not sure if I understand the question... but you *can* use the *component* which is used with the `edit` option for the "Classic" block. The WordPress Gutenberg team doesn't forbid us from using the component. 2) That is done internally by WordPress via the REST API. So just make sure your meta is registered in the REST API. And in your block attributes, set the source to `meta`. And have you tried the code? Did it work as expected? :)

Comment: And while the approach in the answer does work (at least for me and for now), you might want to consider using inner blocks. You know, a block where you got the `+` (add block) button, which allows you to add blocks in a block.

Comment: I will give it a go this weekend. Admittedly, I've got a LOT of work to do coming up to speed with Gutenberg. The flexibility and power of metadata in the WordPress environment has made it as much a part of the final product as the content. I don't see the benefit of porting any metadata management on the edit page into the browser side environment.

Comment: I could understand what you're trying to achieve with the full-featured WYSIWYG/TinyMCE editor - it is indeed easier for those who're familiar with it more than with the block editor, but I suggested the inner blocks just in case you were not aware of it. :) And I'm looking forward to hearing from you - hopefully the code works for you as well.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. The ClassicEdit class is pretty powerful for something they're moving away from (eventually).

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! But note though, the solution *may* not work in future Gutenberg releases. However, when that day comes, you can always post another question. Or come back to this question. :)

Comment: Thank you again. I'm switching between Classic and Gutenberg way too much. I want to move to Gutenberg but I'm much more efficient and productive in Classic.

Comment: I'm sure you are, but Gutenberg isn't that hard to learn and you'll do good with it as time passes by. Cheers. :)